# How is it possible to use get_IsConnectedToInternet in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Any clu how we can use `get_IsConnectedToInternet` property under C#?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965311(v=vs.85).aspx

Thank you!

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027791/specific-network-interface-ipv4-availability-no-connectivity-local-internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified version of the call.
It tells if you have an internet connection available, not if you are connected.

```
    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState( out int Description, int ReservedValue ) ;

    public static bool IsConnectedToInternet( )
    {
        try
        {
            int Desc;
            return InternetGetConnectedState(out Desc, 0);
        }
        catch 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @PArt If you post an alternative solution I would be glad to upvote yours. Or at least provide the information on which you have based your comment.