# ManagedWifi detect need open browser to enter additional info

Tags: c#, .net, wifi

We have embedded system on Windows 8.1 and 10 with our own OS shell, we don't allow to open browser.  We need a way to detect that when connecting to WiFi network with ManagedWifi, that it requires to open a browser for additional info.  Is there a way to determine this?  I didn't see anything in ManagedWifi.  How does Windows figure this out that it needs to open (default) browser automatically?  Note - that it appears they added something in Windows 10 to do this - Windows 8.1 doesn't seem to automatically open browser.

Comment: See following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol.  Not sure but it looks like it uses TLS.  Says following : the majority of implementations of EAP-TLS require client-side X.509 certificates without giving the option to disable the requirement.  I suspect when you login with webpage a certificate is download, then when you connect to WIFI the certificate is sent.  I assume without the certificate a status will be returns indicating the failure.

Comment: If it is EAP it can be configured through WiFi profile XML. If it is Captive Portal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) then I have no idea how to avoid that. By default when you connected to WiFi Windows pings MS server first. And depending on answer shows login page.

Comment: [This is the Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/captive-portals) on how it does the detection. [This one](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netgeeks/2018/02/20/why-do-i-get-an-internet-explorer-or-edge-popup-open-when-i-get-connected-to-my-corpnet-or-a-public-network/) has even more details and the linked article is good as well.

Comment: You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8027856/2557128) and its comments useful.